# How to copy and rename latest timestamped csv files using SSIS

Tags: ssis

I am trying to move files from Folder A to Folder B with the aid of a SSIS package. Folder A has an 3 csv files generated every hour with a timestamp in the filename (The file naming convention is consistent). My objective is to run a SSIS package which will take the latest iteration of these 3 csv's and make a copy of it in Folder B, and remove the datetime tag which is currently appended to the file name.

When it is moved to Folder B, all 3 files will be processed and transformed for ingestion into SQL - which I have already been able to take care of.

[image]

Given it is my first attempt with SSIS, I am not sure of where to even begin solving the problem. After some googling, I have tried to use from foreach containers, but that doesnt seem to help much.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Have a good day :)

Comment: You would have to use C# script task and write your code in C#.  You can read the directory, get the latest filenames, and then do whatever you need with them.

Comment: Use a foreach loop container. This can be used to iterate through files in a folder. In each iteration of the loop, the foreach loop container will assign the filename to a variable. You can then use that variable in an execute sql task to insert the file name into a table. After the foreach has finished use that table to iterate another foreach loop to move the files